# Azure IoT Edge EFLOW installation interrupted, now fails validation

Tags: windows, azure-iot-edge

I was installing Azure IoT Edge on Windows (EFLOW) via Windows Admin centre when my internet connection dropped temporarily and the install failed.
When I try the install again I get:

Error
Target device evaluation error
Message
Unsupported: Device not clean, Azure IoT Edge for Linux on Windows components detected (Azure IoT Edge PS module).

How can I clean up the machine so I can install again please?

[image]

Comment: Did you try using Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

If the wizard disappears or fails, there's no way to bring it up again. The solution is to start the deployment process again. Before reinstalling, you need to begin by removing EFLOW from the target device by following these steps:

1. Open Settings on Windows 10
2. Select Add or Remove Programs
3. Select Azure IoT Edge app
4. Select Uninstall

Once the Azure IoT Edge app is correctly removed from the target device, you can start the deployment again.

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks for this. I tried and Windows won't remove it. Event Viewer just shows 'Product: Azure IoT Edge -- Removal failed.'
Guess I need to try and unpick this manually :/

Comment: I managed to remove 'Azure IoT Edge' using the apps screen in Windows Admin Centre. Now I have a problem creating the network switch in Hyper-V. On we go ...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The problem for me was that (strangely) I had a parallel installation of Windows Power Shell on my d: drive under ' users<name>\documents'. Very odd. I deleted this and am now up and running.